# Passing pointer to self in constructor c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

In a basic game code that I'm developing, I have each separate area of the "map" have a separate Area class that handles combat and a variety of other basic functions. Each entity contained within the Area has a pointer to that Area so it can access Area functions and whatnot, however that pointer is apparently getting deleted or something wonky is happening, because when it tries to dereference it, I get all sorts of run-time errors.

Is it happening because I'm giving each NPC a pointer to the Area in its constructor?

Area Constructor

```
Area::Area(Game& game, std::string name, std::string id)
: GameState(game), game(game), player(game.getPlayer()), log(game, "log", 0.0f, 90.0f, 32, game.getFont("Times"), sf::Color::White)
{
    game.clearStrings();
    this->id = id;
    this->name = name;
    game.timer.restart();
    player.setArea(this);
    game.addString(DisplayString(&game, name, name + "title", game.getFont("Celt"), 10.0f, 10.0f, 64, sf::Color::White));
    //
    this->addEnemy(NPC(game, this, "Skeleton", "skel", 30, 0, 7, 10, 5, 5));
    this->addEnemy(NPC(game, this, "Skeleton", "skel", 30, 0, 7, 10, 5, 5));
    int offsetY = 0;
    for (std::map<std::string, NPC>::iterator it = enemies.begin(); it != enemies.end(); ++it)
    {
        game.addString(DisplayString(&game, it->second.getName(), it->first, game.getFont("Times"), WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, 64, sf::Color::White));
        DisplayString& name = game.getString(it->second.getID());
        game.addString(DisplayString(&game, std::to_string(it->second.hp) + " / " + std::to_string(it->second.maxhp), it->second.getID() + "hp", game.getFont("Times"), WINDOW_WIDTH, name.Text.getGlobalBounds().height, 64, sf::Color::White));

        name.setPos(WINDOW_WIDTH - name.Text.getGlobalBounds().width, offsetY);
        offsetY += name.Text.getGlobalBounds().height;

        DisplayString& hp =  game.getString(it->second.getID() + "hp");
        hp.setPos(WINDOW_WIDTH - hp.Text.getGlobalBounds().width, offsetY+name.Text.getGlobalBounds().height);
        offsetY += hp.Text.getGlobalBounds().height;
    }
}
```

NPC Constructor

```
NPC::NPC(Game& game, Area* area, std::string name, std::string id, int hp, int ap, int agil, int str, int dmg, int speed)
: game(game)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->hp = hp;
    this->maxhp = hp;
    this->ap = ap;
    this->dmg = dmg;
    this->agil = agil;
    this->str = str;
    this->speed = speed;
    this->area = area;
    this->id = id + std::to_string(game.enemyID++);
}
```

This is where I run into troubles dereferencing the area pointer of the NPC class

```
void NPC::attack(Player& player)
{
    if (rand() % 100 + 1 < 5)
    {
        int damage = 2 * (this->dmg + (rand() % 6 - 3));
        player.hp -= damage;
        //any of these area pointers in the debugger show up with garbage data
        area->log.addLine(this->name + " critically strikes " + player.getName() + " for " + std::to_string(damage) + "!");
    }
    else
    {
        if (rand() % 100 + 1 > 15)
        {
            int damage = this->dmg + (rand() % 6 - 3);
            player.hp -= damage;
            area->log.addLine(this->name + " hits " + player.getName() + " for " + std::to_string(damage) + "!");
        }
        else
        {
            area->log.addLine(player.getName() + " dodges!");
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that there's no shenanigans going on from the Area constructor, to the NPC constructor, to the Attack function. The Area constructor completes, then the game calls the Area's update function, which immediately calls Attack, and nowhere in between is the area pointer being deleted or in any other way modified.

I apologize for the incredibly verbose answer and for kinda dumping a bunch of code at you, but I'm new at all the stuff and really didn't know what to cut out to condense it. If you need any more code to get a better idea of what's going on, I will gladly provide it, I've just banged my head at this for days trying to sort it out with no headway made.

Edit: adding some code that leads to the construction of Area (cut out extraneous code)

```
void InitState::update()
{
    if(main.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (main.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                main.close();
                game.Stop();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyReleased:
                switch (event.key.code)
                {
                    break;
                case sf::Keyboard::Key::Return:
                    switch (var)
                    {
                    case NAME:
                        if (writing)
                        {
                            game.delIcon("inputbox");
                            player.setName(game.getString("input").Text.getString());
                            game.addArea(Area(game, "The Cave", "cave"));
                            game.setState(&game.getArea("cave"));
                        }
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

InitState is a GameState, which Area is as well. When the game loops, it calls state->update() and render(), so when the game sets a state, it switches over to that class's update and render functions.

Area's update function

```
void Area::update()
{
    if (game.getWindow().isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (game.getWindow().pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                game.getWindow().close();
                game.Stop();
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased)
            {
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Key::Return)
                {
                    doCombat(); // calls attack functions for NPC and player
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT EDIT: More code!
areas is an std::map

```
void Game::addArea(Area area)
{
    areas.emplace(area.getID(), area);
}

Area& Game::getArea(std::string id)
{
    return areas.find(id)->second;
}
```

Comment: Where are the `Area` objects kept? Perhaps in a container that dynamically expands/contracts? Post the **exact** runtime error messaging you're receiving please.

Comment: In an std::map<std::string, Area> in the main Game class. The exception is: 
Unhandled exception at 0x0021BA56 in simple_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC. This is triggered by the commented line in Attack

Comment: The value `0xCCCCCCCC` is used by Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler in debug-mode to fill-pattern **uninitialized stack memory**. Were I to hazard a guess, I would say you're sending an `Area` address of a local variable to the constructor for your Player, *then* adding it to the map by-value (which makes an independent copy). Without more code its not possible to say for sure. What **exactly** are you passing to the npc constructor ? Posting the code that leads to the construction chain (the construction of Area, of npc, etc) would be very telling.

Comment: updated OP with relevant code

Comment: Well that partly explains where the Area is constructed, and I can only assume that your `addArea` takes a const-reference and make a copy for the map. But it still leaves the question of how an NPC gets ahold of said-area once in the map, and more importantly, does `Game::getArea()` return a *reference* to the mapped Area? If not, that is a huge problem right there. A by-value return value would be UB.  Still unclear how the area in the map eventually makes it to the NPC constructor by-address.

Comment: We need to see how permanent Areas are created and how pointers to them are obtained. (Is that in `addArea`? The call site creates only a temporary Area.)

Comment: None of this seemed to be a problem with DisplayString, where all the relevant addString and getString functions are working nicely, but is that because I implemented a copy constructor for DisplayString, but not for Area?

Comment: Possibly related: If `id` is **not** in the map, your `getArea(id)` invokes UB, as it dereferences the resulting `end()` iterator returned on search-failure. You're *sure* `getID()` is returning a `std::string` of "cave" and not "The Cave", right ?

Comment: Indeed it is, I am now certain the issue that I'm struggling with is the one that Frunsi describes in his answer, where I don't have a copy constructor and thus the pointers to the member objects are referencing a deleted object.

Comment: The problem has been entirely fixed by implementing copy constructors for the objects Area and NPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an instance of your Area class on the stack:

In `void InitState::update()`:

```
//...
game.addArea(Area(game, "The Cave", "cave"));
//...
```

Then your Game::addArea() creates a **copy** of it.

But you probably have not defined a copy constructor for `class Area`, which handles all the gory details. So, the (automatically created) copy of your area object probably contains pointers pointing to objects managed by the original area instance, which was deleted exactly after the above line.

There are some different strategies to solve your problem: a simple one: use heap allocation (`new Area(..)` instead of just `Area(..)`) everywhere, and use smart pointers where applicable.

You should read about C++ heap and stack allocation, automatic memory, references, especially const references, and so on.

Maybe this link is an introduction for you: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/

**EDIT**: By the way, it is good style to mark your objects "non-copyable", whenever you don't want to or cannot provide a copy constructor. Or if you just want to disallow copies of them. [Non-copyable Mixin](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Non-copyable_Mixin)

Comment: This is exactly the problem that I was running into, thank you. I've decided it will probably be easier to implement copy constructors than have to deal with the stack and all that business. I'm just wondering, because I'm running into issues now where not everything is being copied correctly, how do things like std::map handle being copied?

Comment: std::map has a copy constructor, so you can just write `a=b` where a and b are of same map type, e.g. `std::map<std::string,Foo>`. However, I would not recommend you to work with copying your object instances .. it will not even 100% work in your case (promised!). You should overthink your stuff, you should especially distinguish between "ownership" and "references"!

Comment: Yeah I'm running into a lot of errors where things are not getting copied correctly even though I have copy constructors, so this is obviously getting hairy quickly. Plenty of things that were working before are now not.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but it may be possible that the call to "**game.timer.restart();**" before the call to "**player.setArea(this);**" is the problem. Perhaps this is causing something to be called that is de-referencing the variable. Try moving the "player.setArea(this);" line to before the "**game.timer.restart();**" line. Or if restart clears that variable, separate the restart operation into a stop and a start operation as follows.

```
game.timer.stop();
player.setArea(this);
game.timer.start();
```

I hope this helps.